# Why is a field missing?

Tags: python, json, gitlab, gitlab-api

There is a Python script that should set a policy for cleaning Docker images

```py
headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": TOKEN}

data_binary = {
    "container_expiration_policy_attributes": {
        "cadence": "1month",
        "enabled": "true",
        "keep_n": "1",
        "older_than": "14d",
        "name_regex": "",
        "name_regex_delete": ".*",
        "name_regex_keep": ".*-master"
    }
}

url = f"https://hidden/api/v4/projects/{str(project_id)}"

r = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data_binary))
json_data = r.json()
pprint.pprint(json_data)
```

It returns an error on startup

```py
{'error': 'allow_merge_on_skipped_pipeline, autoclose_referenced_issues, '
          'auto_devops_enabled, auto_devops_deploy_strategy, '
          'auto_cancel_pending_pipelines, build_coverage_regex, '
          'build_git_strategy, build_timeout, builds_access_level, '
          'ci_config_path, ci_default_git_depth, '
          'ci_forward_deployment_enabled, container_registry_enabled, '
          'container_expiration_policy_attributes, default_branch, '
          'description, emails_disabled, forking_access_level, '
          'issues_access_level, lfs_enabled, merge_requests_access_level, '
          'merge_method, name, '
          'only_allow_merge_if_all_discussions_are_resolved, '
          'only_allow_merge_if_pipeline_succeeds, pages_access_level, path, '
          'printing_merge_request_link_enabled, public_builds, '
          'remove_source_branch_after_merge, repository_access_level, '
          'request_access_enabled, resolve_outdated_diff_discussions, '
          'shared_runners_enabled, snippets_access_level, tag_list, '
          'visibility, wiki_access_level, avatar, suggestion_commit_message, '
          'repository_storage, compliance_framework_setting, packages_enabled, '
          'service_desk_enabled, issues_enabled, jobs_enabled, '
          'merge_requests_enabled, wiki_enabled, snippets_enabled, '
          'approvals_before_merge, '
          'external_authorization_classification_label, import_url, '
          'fallback_approvals_required are missing, at least one parameter '
          'must be provided'}
```

as I understand the key is the following

```
...container_expiration_policy_attributes... are missing
```

Although I pointed the field out. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add Content-type

```py
headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": TOKEN,
           "Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
```